# Why can't mbstring detect latin1 characters as cp1252?

Tags: php, character-encoding

ASCII characters are detected as valid latin1, but not [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

```
mb_detect_encoding("a",["ISO-8859-1"],true);   // "ISO-8859-1"  
mb_detect_encoding("a",["Windows-1252"],true); // false
```

The additional characters in the range 80-9F are detectable as both:

```
mb_detect_encoding("\x80",["ISO-8859-1"],true);   // "ISO-8859-1"  
mb_detect_encoding("\x80",["Windows-1252"],true); // "Windows-1252"
```

But common extended characters are not. Take the `é` character at `0xE9`. PHP detects it as ISO, but not the superset:

```
mb_detect_encoding("\xE9",["ISO-8859-1"],true);   // "ISO-8859-1"  
mb_detect_encoding("\xE9",["Windows-1252"],true); // false
```

Converting the additional characters to UTF-8 requires using the Windows charset, which works as expected:

```
mb_convert_encoding("a\xE9\x80","UTF-8","Windows-1252"); // aé€
mb_convert_encoding("a\xE9\x80","UTF-8","ISO-8859-1");   // aé<control>
```

I can live with the limitation (detect as ISO, convert as Windows), but I'd love to know why this is the case.

Comment: I take your point, but this is an academic question. Verifying a single byte against a single character set in which that byte is a valid character is not guessing. I don't understand how this function can possibly fail at doing that and wanted to understand why.

Comment: Thanks! Well at least I'm not crazy. That's good enough for me today!

Comment: Begs the question of how it came to be that knowledge of the character encoding was not agreed upon, was lost or was not communicated in the first place.

Comment: @tomblodget Not that I agree the question is begged, but my software is often presented (by customers) with files that declare no character encoding or an incorrect character encoding. While that can be agreed upon (documentation) or communicated (http headers) I prefer to at least try to handler user errors

Comment: The answer to detect is the nice function: https://kence.org/2019/11/27/detecting-windows-1252-encoding/